# No such know host issue - API Azure Load Balancer

Tags: azure

Is there any limitations about Azure Load Balancer, I mean there is a limit of transactions?

I am facing an issue with an API, I am consuming my API that it is behind an Azure Load Balance, and from a Xamarin App, I often get the next error: "not such known host", and the response from the API is a kind of slow, but if the API is not behind the load balancer, the response is fast.

would anyone know what could be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Refer to the doc to learn about a service limits: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#load-balancer

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @CSharpRocks for the comment

As per this [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/networking/check-usage-against-limits#azure-cli),
We can check the Limits  of the Azure Resources by using the below command in  Azure CLI,

```cs
az network list-usages --location eastus --out table
```

[image]

- The Load Balancer limit is ***`1000`***